# Entity framework with Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, entity-framework

I am developing a project while my internship.In this project I am taking data from database and making operations on them with services. Then I send them to the client.

My problem : I made a wcf-linq service but I don't know how can I develop a similar entity framework with WEB SERVICE .

Can anyone send me an example of Entity framework With web service.(In .Net Framework 4 , there is no web service project. It's only available in 3.5 )

Thank you in advance

Comment: when you say web services do you mean SOAP XML web services instead of WCF? in this case you need to create some serializable business entities and lists of them and expose these types via web services to the client application. EF will be used only to load data from database and pass it to the web services to populate those entities, I would _not_ expose EF entities directly to the client.

Comment: Hello , I know that EF will be used only to load data from database and pass it to the web services to populate those entities. I will use EF in my service. But in my project, my supervisor asked me to create a WCF service with linq(dbml) , and similar WEB SERVICE with EF. In visual stdio when you set your .Net framework 3.5 , you can create a project as ASP.Net web service Application. I dont know it is SOAP XML or anything. I know Wcf but Dont know anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it by creating a webservice project and writing my methods under [WebMethod]s. I thought it has interface like wcf but it has not.

Comment: this is old architecture for the web-services. Try to use the WCF service project pattern.